# Can't generate code128 barcode

Tags: miktex, pstricks, pst-barcode, barcodes

Googling already for five hours. I'm very newbie to LaTeX. :(
I use pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX in TeXworks (yep, it ran on Windows). Packages from MiKTeX.

Sample code, that didn't work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-barcode,pstricks-add}

\begin{document}
    \psset{unit=1in}
    \begin{pspicture}(3.5,1.2)
        \psbarcode{^10412345678}{includetext}{code128}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

So it give an error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \c@lor@to@ps 

l.11 ...arcode{^10412345678}{includetext}{code128}
```

I tried to genereate a QR code,

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}(0.7in,0.7in)
        \psbarcode{ctan.org}{}{qrcode}
    \end{pspicture}
    %
    \begin{pspicture}(0.7in,0.7in)
        \psbarcode{tug.org}{}{qrcode}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

but problem the same :(

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \c@lor@to@ps 

l.7 \psbarcode{ctan.org}{}{qrcode}

?
```

Also tried standalone code128 package from ctan.org (code taken from documentarion):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\input code128
\X=.5mm        % width of line
\barheight=1cm % height
\code{text}       \bigskip 
\end
```

It can't find `\end`

```
Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \end.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> ...eX/LaTeX training 16.05/code128/test-2.tex"

?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For pstricks you need to use latex not pdflatex or use xelatex.

Or add `\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}` and use `pdflatex --shell-escape`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-barcode,pstricks-add}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}
    \psset{unit=1in}
    \begin{pspicture}(3.5,1.2)
        \psbarcode{123456789012}{includetext}{code128}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It work perfectly on first computer, but on another it fall with `Package pst-pdf Warning: pspicture No. 1 undefined.` and create two pdf's: `test.pdf`, and `test-autopp.pdf`

Comment: latex doesn't output anything, xelatex output blank pdf :(

Comment: @EgorEgorov in the form above, with `auto-pst-pdf` you should use `pdflatex --shell-escape` but xelatex and latex never just do nothing. If there is an error the details will be in the `.log` file. Compare the log files on the two computers perhaps one has old versions of the packages.