# Why does auto-pst-pdf create two PDFs

Tags: auto-pst-pdf

I used [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/369949/227165) to create my own barcode:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-2mm,-1mm)(33mm,14mm)
\psbarcode{1410261}{guardwhitespace height=0.5 }{code128}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

and it works, it's just that two pdfs are created, namely `barcode.pdf` and `barcode-pics.pdf`. Which one of those is the `correct` one that I should use in my projects? The `barcode-pics.pdf` is a little bit smaller, than the other one. I also tried to add `[cleanup={log,aux,dvi,ps,pdf}]` as an option to `auto-pst-pdf`, like it is suggested in the package documentation, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Well, you are using the `standalone` class. Try it with `article` and you'll see the difference.

Comment: Oh, thanks. Kinda stupid of me :)